# How to draw graph in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to draw graph in java script. Let me share my problem with simple example.

```
Ind vs Aus cricket match.
     X axis- Overs
     Y axis- Runs
```

I want to show runs scored in each over by both teams in same graph. Can i show them together?

your experience will be useful to me. hoping for help.

would be grateful for help...thanks in advance,,

Comment: There are a ton of plugins for this. I have used <a href="http://www.highcharts.com">Highcharts</a> and it works really well.

Comment: For what it's worth, your example isn't very helpful to those of us who have no idea how cricket is played.

Comment: i tried simple graph(graph.js)..but, now i am able to show graph for both teams separately but, i want it together..

Comment: jqplot is one I've used.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/flot/ jquery Flot === best plugin for charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Google Visualization API:](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

It includes classes to build datatables and then visualize them with different types of charts:

Example from the [Google Visualiation Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');
  data.addRow(["A", 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["B", 2, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["C", 4, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["D", 8, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["E", 7, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["F", 7, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["G", 8, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["H", 4, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["I", 2, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["J", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["K", 3, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["L", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["M", 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["N", 1, 0.5, 1]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
          );
}
```

This will create a line chart with the X and Y axis which is what you are try to do.

Answer (score 0):

[gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) is a great choice for charts for web. It uses javascript to produce graphs in SVG and, in old versions of IE, VML, which makes it a great cross-browser starting point - it works in IE6 and above and doesn't need flash. Another good advantage is, using SVG/VML DOM elements controlled by a javascript object means your graph elements can be made highly interactive and manipulated in javascript at any time.

Example code ([from doc barchart examples](http://g.raphaeljs.com/barchart2.html)):

```
r.hbarchart(10, 250, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]]).hover(fin, fout);
```

That line creates a two-variable bar chart which calls mousein and mouseout callback functions on each element which you could use to show related information e.g., in their example, the exact values. A two variable bar chart is probably a good way to represent two teams' scoring by over for one innings. A [graphael dot chart](http://g.raphaeljs.com/dotchart.html) might be a better good option if there are multiple overs and multiple innings - one for each team. There are other chart types supported too - see the demo examples on the main project page above.